# How to assign ObservableCollection to var(query) in C#.

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I am working with WPF application and I want to assign a value of the `var` query to the `ObservableCollection`. So how can I assign it?

```
userDetail = Query as ObservableCollection<UserDatail>;
```

This will give me `null`.

My code is here

```
        userDetail = new ObservableCollection<UserDatail>();
        SampleDB conn = new SampleDB(Helper.GetPath());
        var Query = from a in conn.UserInfo
        select      
          a;

        userDetail = Query as ObservableCollection<UserDatail>;
```

See I don't want to use `foreach` loop to add this one by one.

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a collection of UserDatail and not UserInfo. If yes try this:

```
    SampleDB conn = new SampleDB(Helper.GetPath());
    var Query = from a in conn.UserInfo
    select      
      a.UserDatail; //I assume each user info object has a UserDatail property

    var userDetail = new ObservableCollection<UserDatail>(Query.ToList());
```

Comment: yes correct but  userDetail is not a var it is object ofObservableCollection<UserDatail> so without var keyword I want to assing direct to ObservableCollection<UserDatail>.

Comment: It doesn;t matter. Remove the var infront og userDetail (in case userDetail is already declared) and the code should work...

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WpfPerfomanceDemo.UserInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WpfPerfomanceDemo.UserDatail>'

Comment: You have to define the  userDeatil variable as ObservableCollection<UserDatail>

Comment: Did you change select a  to select a.UserDatail in your linq query?

Comment: I had try select a to a.UserDetail,but I am not able to get a.UserDetail UserDetail is my class and inside the class I have member and contsructor for this.

Comment: Can u post UserInfo and UserDetail classes>

Comment: Yes sure see UserInfo is my talbe and UserDetail is my class.I am just posting my UserDatil class.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ObservableCollection constructor with IEnumerable argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc679169.aspx).
Just `var userDetail = new ObservableCollection<UserDatail>(Query);`

Comment: userDetail is not var it is also object of ObservableCollection<UserDatail>

Comment: it's give me error   cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WpfPerfomanceDemo.UserInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WpfPerfomanceDemo.UserDatail>'

Comment: Change generic type of observable collection.

Comment: You should create ObservableCollection<UserInfo> instead <UserDetail> because your query returns collection of UserInfo objects

Comment: but UserDetail is my class which contain all the member and contrucoter for this so if I could change the UserDetail to UserInfo then I want to add more record through UserDetail at that time it will create a proble.

Comment: Your question was about converting linq query to ObservableCollection. Other logic and querying you can choose by yourself.